# Clubhouse ring around user image when person talks, how to do that on flutter?

Tags: flutter

Any package I could use to get that ring type to show? I'm doing the voice call tests with agora sdk, but can't get the ring to show around the image when a person is talking.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the uid of each user, you can set a border around the image of the user using [activeSpeaker](https://docs.agora.io/en/Voice/API%20Reference/flutter/rtc_channel/RtcChannelEventHandler/activeSpeaker.html) method, which returns the uid of the currently speaking user

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is use the combination of two containers with padding on both:

I've created a dartpad:
[Club house ring](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/?id=d0d30c2ca03c67ae1f0688a3209aed8a&null_safety=true)

The first container is for the outer most ring, and the second container is for the image plus the white ring, the padding gives the effect of the ring that you want.